# unsigned and signed values in C

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

here is the question:

in the Book 'Computer Systems: A Programmer’s Perspective' section 2.2.5

it said that if an unsigned value is comparing with a signed value, all values will be compared in the unisnged format. like this

```
if(-1 < 0u)
{
    // will not print this line because -1 will be translated to 255.
    printf("all changed to unsigned format");
}
```

I tried this code in VC6 SP6, the string was NOT outputed. And everything looks good because we all know that -1 was translated to 255.

but when I read the book 'Expert C Programming Deep C Secrets' section 1.10

It said that if my complier uses the ANSI C Standard, this code will print "-1 < (unsigned char)1: ANSI":

```
if(-1 < (unsigned char)1)
{
    printf("-1 < (unsigned char)1: ANSI");
}
else
{
    printf("-1 NOT Less than (unsigned char)1: K&R");    
}
```

The output I got was: -1 < (unsigned char)1: ANSI.

I'm using the VC6 SP6 complier.

and why is this happening?

according to the book 'Computer Systems: A Programmer’s Perspective'

-1 < (unsigned char)1 will make -1 be translated as an unsigned value. so it will become sth like this:

255 < 1

and this should not print out the line -1 < (unsigned char)1: ANSI.

can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: -1 is not cast into 255 but into `unsigned int` width in the example `-1 < 0u`. And in my mind (I'm not sure), `implicit cast` is from the lower type to the higher type, that's to say, in the case `-1 < (unsigned char)1`, `(unsigned char)1` will be cast into type `int`.

Comment: @Stan yeah you're right:) it will be read as 4294967295 here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if(-1 < (unsigned char)1)`

In this case both operands are promoted to `int`.

`if( -1 < 0u )`

In this case both operands are converted to `unsigned int`.

The following quotes prove me right.

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows: 
> — If either operand is of type long
>   double, the other shall be converted to long double. 
> — Otherwise, if
>   either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double. 
> —
>   Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to
>   float. 
> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed
>   on both operands.54) 
> — Then, if either operand is unsigned long the
>   other shall be converted to unsigned long. 
> — Otherwise, if one operand
>   is a long int and the other unsigned int, then if a long int can
>   represent all the values of an unsigned int, the unsigned int shall be
>   converted to a long int; otherwise both operands shall be converted to
>   unsigned long int. 
> — Otherwise, if either operand is long, the other
>   shall be converted to long. 
> — Otherwise, if either operand is
>   unsigned, the other shall be converted to unsigned. [Note: otherwise,
>   the only remaining case is that both operands are int ]

And this (***integral promotions***):

> An rvalue of type char, signed char, unsigned char, short int, or
>   unsigned short int can be converted to an rvalue of type int if int
>   can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source
>   rvalue can be converted to an rvalue of type unsigned int.

To be perfectly honest, the quotes are from the C++03 standard, but they hold for C as well.